# iOS development with Flutter on Windows?

Tags: ios, flutter, virtual-machine, simulator

I'd like to develope an iOS-app using Flutter. But unfortunately I'm having a Windows PC, so my question is if there are any good working iOS simulators that might be working with the IDE I'm using (intelliJ). Or is it better if I install a VM with macOS on it and develop there?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: the problem is only the build phase, you can develop on windows but if you want to build .ipa file then have to use macos

Comment: A new feature added to `flutlab.io` recently, you can now make builds to test your app without mac, I wrote an article about it you can check it here

https://medium.com/@azozsahb99/create-a-flutter-ios-build-without-mac-911c0e3553c5

Answer (score 1):

Edit Mai 6, 2022:

https://codemagic.io/start/

You can build your iOS Apps here, but you will not be able to test them on a real device.

---

The Build System of macOS **is required to compile and distribute Apps** for iOS and macOS.

If you read the License of macOS carefully, you will recognise that it is not allowed to install it anywhere but on a mac device.

There are workaround known in the community like a "Hackintosh". I would not recommend doing it that way. You will most likely have to buy specific hardware in order to get it going smoothly. For that money, you can already buy a real mac. Note, in order to release the App on the AppStore or test it on a real device, you can not use a "Hackintosh" aswell.

There are Macs out there that come at a price tag starting at around $400, and they are more than enough to build apps and be used for programming. Have a look at MacBook Pros 2012 to 2015 or iMacs from 2013 to 2015, or have a look at a Mac mini. I started this way aswell and I don't regret.

Having said that, building your Apps for Android only is a good way to get started with Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible. mac is needed because flutter runs in flutter using xcode build. The ios design can be implemented on windows. cupertinoWidget

Comment: What about having macOS on a VM?

Comment: well... I haven't run it. Maybe it will run in vm